# How do I get rid of this error when working with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm building a simple blog app to learn using next and mongoose. Right now I'm receiving the error "TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.models is undefined".

I have a model for the blogposts. postModel.js looks like this:

```
import { Schema, models, model } from "mongoose"

const postSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String },
})

const Post = models.Post || model("Post", postSchema)

export default Post
```

My index.js looks like this:

```
import { Header } from "../components/Header"
import { BlogPosts } from "../components/BlogPosts"
import BlogPostForm from "../components/BlogPostForm"
import { useUser } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client"
import Post from "../models/postModel"
import connectMongo from "../utils/connectMongo"

export default function Home({ posts }) {
    const { user } = useUser()

    

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <div className="blog">
                <BlogPosts posts={posts} />
                {user && <BlogPostForm />}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("CONNECTING SERVERSIDE")
        await connectMongo()
        console.log("CONNECTED SERVERSIDE")
        const posts = await Post.find()
        console.log("TEEEST")
        // Post.watch().on("change", () => console.log("NU JÄVLAR!!"))
        console.log("TEEEST")

        return {
            props: {
                posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)),
            },
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Like this, the app works without errors.
However, I want to listen to changes in the mongodb and rerender the blogpost component in my blog, so that when I add a post the list of posts immediately rerenders.

When I add a useEffect like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        Post.watch().on("change", () => {
            console.log("UPDATE")
        })
    }, [])
```

I just get the error "TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.models is undefined".

This error has been bugging me from time to time while building the app - it would seem that there is something wrong with an import or export - but in that case I don't see why it suddenly gives me this error when I try to add a useEffect and not before?

I have tried changing imports and exports back and forth but nothing is working. Please help!

I believe it has something to do with not being connected to my mongodb?
I have tried changing my exports and imports back and forth. I've made sure I'm not importing Post in any file where it's not used (that caused the same error earlier). I've also ask ChatGPT for help but to no avail. I have followed tutorials where my code (atleast in the postModel.js) is identical, so it shouldn't be anything wrong with that file.

EDIT:

This is my connectDB file:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true)

const connectMongo = async () => mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)

export default connectMongo
```

Comment: I useEffect called before or after connecting to the DB?

Comment: Not quite sure. I run the connectMongo function only in getServerSideProps in the index.js and and in an api call to create posts.

Comment: I added "useUnifiedTopology: true,"

to my connectMongo function. No luck still.

Comment: It shouldn't be anything wrong with the model atleast. I tried console logging mongoose.connection.readyState inside a useEffect in index.js and that gives me this:
TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default().connection is undefined

So basically I guess Im not connected to mongodb when it renders but I dont understand what I should do to make sure Im connected before?

Comment: useEffect calls Post.watch(), so if mongoose hasn't connected before it is called, I'm not sure how it would behave

Comment: The thing is, even without useEffect, I can't use any mongoose code inside my react component even though I've imported mongoose. It just says it's not a function for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, error messages could be misleading. One way to look at the problem because objects (or references) from mongoose is not being imported; `import mongoose from "mongoose"`, therefore being undefined.

Another way of looking at this problem or the truth is that ... it is also an issue because of how mongoose and webpack are interacting with each other.

When your code is being executed, you would encounter the error here `mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)` as "mongoose" is an undefined object.

You can fix the problem by simply changing your mongoose version into an older version. After running some tests, the version that would fix the problem is `"mongoose": "^5.10.14"`

As a friendly reminder, try to keep front-end and back-end applications separated even if you are developing under a "full-stack" framework. This could fix future problems from arising.

For references: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5610.